# Is there a way to output a link to a file with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, command-prompt

I have some code to sort a text and output info on it.
How it works is you copy a text a paste it into a text(.txt) file and save the file where the python file is saved. Then you go into the command prompt and type `python3 the_name_of_the_python_file.py the_name_of_the_text_file.txt`. When you run it, it outputs "All counted!". After that you have a new .txt file where the python file is saved and it tells you the number of words and unique words in the text file you attached. The new file will also list out what words are the most to least used.

Is there a way to get my code to output "All counted!" and then a link like thing that I can click on to open the new file?

Here is my code:

```
import sys
text_file = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
word_list = text_file.read().split(",")
word_list = "".join(word_list)
word_list = word_list.split(".")
word_list = "".join(word_list)
word_list = word_list.split(" ")
file_name = []
file_name = sys.argv[1].split(".")
text_file.close()
NumWords = 0
NumUniqueWords = 0
Words = {}
for i in word_list:
    if i not in Words.keys():
        NumWords += 1
        NumUniqueWords += 1
        Words[i.lower()] = 1
    else:
        NumWords += 1
        Words[i] += 1

def get_key(val):
    for key, value in Words.items():
        if value == val:
            return key

newfile = open(file_name[0] + "-count.txt", "w")
newfile.write("Total Words - {}\nUnique Words - {}\n\n".format(NumWords, NumUniqueWords))
for i in range(len(Words)):
    newfile.write("{} - {}\n".format(get_key(max(Words.values())), max(Words.values())))
    del(Words[get_key(max(Words.values()))])
newfile.close()
print("All counted!")
```

I do have things in my code to eliminate ","'s and "."'s and the same word capitalized or lowercase.

Comment: If you print out the file name in console, your console application might make it a link. Would that suffice? Or where do you want the link to be? Maybe in a dialog using tkinter/similar?  Maybe in a Toast Notification? Make a shortcut to desktop?

Comment: I would like to have link be outputted wherever I run the code(command prompt or in app display thing; whatever it's called )  such that I click on it and it opens or brings me to the new file.

Comment: I think this question should be clarified. Note that making "links" to console is not something you can decide using python code. Either all file paths are clickable, or none are (depending on what kind of console people are using to run your code).

Comment: Sooooooo, if the console I am using supports clickable file paths then that would be how I could have my "links"(outputting the file with along side the "All counted!")?